# Simple inequality .

Tags: calculus

Show that $x+y+z \ge 3$ when $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$

Was struggling with this for a long time. Tried to switch members. substitute $x={1 \over yz}$ none got me close to the proof.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the AM-GM inequality.

$$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq (xyz)^{1/3}.$$

Now, since $xyz=1$, it follows that $xyz^{1/3}=1$ and so, multiplying through by $3$ gives

$$x+y+z \geq 3,$$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Try to apply  AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure others will provide a traditional solution using AM-GM inequalities and such. I'm just adding an alternative approach.

Observe, that when we raise this to a power which is a multiple of 3, let's say $3n$, we get $(xyz)^n$ as the middle term, and the rest of the terms are of course nonnegative. Using $n=1$, we get

$$(x+y+z)^3=6xyz + \ldots$$
The lowest bound for $x+y+z$ is therefore

$$x+y+z\geq \sqrt[3]{6}\approx 1.82$$
It's good as a lower bound, but it doesn't prove the requested inequality, it's too weak. It does give us an idea, however. If we do it for general $n$, we just have to remember the multinomial coefficient (the coefficient in front of $x^i y^j z^k$), which is $\frac{(i+j+k)!}{i!j!k!}$. In our case, for the power $3n$, the middle coefficient that stands in front of $(xyz)^n$ is

$$\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}$$
and the estimate of our $x+y+z$ is

$$x+y+z\geq \left(\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}\right)^{1/(3n)}$$
This inequality holds for every $n$ and the estimate gets better in the limit $n\to\infty$. In fact,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3}\right)^{1/(3n)}=3$$
can be proven with the use of Stirling approximation, which is asymptotically exact, thus completing our proof.